# Custom price range for a filter in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price

I want a custom price range for filter like this:

- 0-1999.
- 2000-4999.
- 5000-8999.

How can I do that?

Comment: This method works great, except I am having trouble with the counts being wrong. I believe that is because this line: $entityCount = count($entityStorage->getSource()); This line doesn't return an accurate count of the entities. Any ideas on what might be the issue?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138139)

Comment: I found the answer:

Replace: 

$entityCount = count($entityStorage->getSource());

with:

$aggregations = $this->dataProvider->getAggregations($entityStorage);
$entityCount = $aggregations['count'];

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138139)

Answer (score 5):

On the Admin Panel, `Stores > Settings > Configuration`.

In the left panel, under Catalog, select Catalog.
Open the Layered Navigation section.
In the Display Product Count field, enable to enter the number of products that is included in parentheses after each filtered item.
Make Price Navigation Steps Calculation by two methods as the following:

Method 1: Automatic (equalize price ranges)
This method is to use the standard algorithm for price navigation. In the Price Navigation Steps Calculation, select the Automatic (Equalize Price Ranges).

[image]

Method 2: Automatic (equalize product counts)

In the Price Navigation Steps Calculation field, select Automatic (equalize product counts) option.

In the Display Price Interval as One Price field, allow showing a single price for many products that are both at the same price if you choose Yes.
In the Interval Division Limit field, offer the threshold for a number of products within a price range. The range cannot be further split beyond this limit. If ignore it, the default value (9) is applied.

[image]

Save Config to complete.

Refer this for more detail - [Configure-price-filter-price-navigation](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-price-filter-price-navigation-magento-2.html)

Comment: i know but step of me different of you. How can i fix it

Answer (score 5):

There's a few steps to adding a custom range algorithm:
 1. Create custom range class implementing `Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm\AlgorithmInterface`
 2. Add algorithm class to `Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm\Repository`
 3. Create plugin on `Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\Price\Step::toOptionArray` so your custom range option is available in the admin panel.

> Vendor/Module/Search/Dynamic/Algorithm/MyCustom.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm;

use Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\DataProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\EntityStorage;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Request\BucketInterface;

class MyCustom implements \Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm\AlgorithmInterface
{
    const RANGE_CALCULATION_MY_CUSTOM = 'my_custom';
    const RANGES = [
        [null, 2000],
        [2000, 5000],
        [5000, 9000],
        [9000, null],
    ];

    /**
     * @var DataProviderInterface
     */
    private $dataProvider;

    /**
     * @param DataProviderInterface $dataProvider
     */
    public function __construct(
        DataProviderInterface $dataProvider
    ) {
        $this->dataProvider = $dataProvider;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getItems(
        BucketInterface $bucket,
        array $dimensions,
        EntityStorage $entityStorage
    ) {
        $entityCount = count($entityStorage->getSource());
        if ($entityCount < 1) {
            return [];
        }

        $data = [];
        $interval = $this->dataProvider->getInterval($bucket, $dimensions, $entityStorage);
        foreach (self::RANGES as $range) {
            $rangeResult = $interval->load($entityCount, null, $range[0], $range[1]);

            $count = count($rangeResult);
            if ($count < 1) {
                continue;
            }

            $data [] = [
                'count' => $count,
                'from' => $range[0],
                'to' => $range[1],
            ];
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm\Repository">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="algorithms" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="my_custom" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm\MyCustom</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Plugin/Config/Source/Price/Step.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Config\Source\Price;

use Vendor\Module\Search\Dynamic\Algorithm\MyCustom;

class Step
{
    public function afterToOptionArray(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\Price\Step $subject,
        array $result
    ) {
        $result[] = [
            'label' => __('My Custom Ranges'),
            'value' => MyCustom::RANGE_CALCULATION_MY_CUSTOM,
        ];

        return $result;
    }
}
```

> Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\Price\Step">
        <plugin name="vendor_custom_price_range" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Config\Source\Price\Step" sortOrder="10" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: I much appreciate the answer... but I got an error report stating... Something went wrong, check and test your Search Engine configurations, reindex catalog and clear cache. Thrown error: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in Vendor\/Module\/Search\/Dynamic\/Algorithm\/MyCustom.php on line 45 which is `$entityCount = count($entityStorage->getSource());`